# Tabbing gives error in proof general/emacs

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-12.04, coq, proof-general

I have emacs 23.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with proof general 4.2. When editing coq files in the "coq Holes" mode (which is the default when I hack coq), I cannot tab. Doing so gives the error

> wrong type argument integer-or-marker-p nil proof general

in the minibuffer. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Some function did not get the right argument. Hard to tell, might happen erverywhere in code. Maybe try current mirror: https://github.com/cpitclaudel/proof-general. What is the value of split-width-threshold?

Comment: In your .emacs, add '(setq debug-on-error t)' - which will generate a stack trace when you get this error.  Add the stack trace to this question (not as a comment) and we might be able to help.